# Dynamically setting up a chain of $http calls to load sequentially numbered json files in Angular 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, factory

I've got a sequence of json files (page1.json, page2.json, etc) that contain the layout details for our pages.

Up until now I've been loading the data for each page when it's needed and everything has been working well, but it's now clear that the page data for every page is needed when the angular app starts - and each page must be in a separate file (to please the designers).

Here's what I've been trying:

```
var app = angular.module("templatesApp", ['bulletComponent', 'popupComponent', 'imageComponent', 'paragraphComponent', 'ngRoute']);

var numberOfPages = 0;
var pageData = [];
var pageIndex = 0;

/*Factory that runs http.get on content.json, used by multiple controllers */
app.factory('content', ['$http', 'completions', 'pages', function($http, completions, pages) {
    var url = 'json/content.json';
    return $http.get(url)
        .success(function(data) {
            // loop through pages and add corresponding page objects to completions.js service
            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                completions.addPage(data[i].title);
                numberOfPages += 1;
            }
            loadPageData(pages, completions);
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            return data;
        });
}]);

var loadPageData = function(pages, completions) {
    console.log("loadPageData called when pageIndex = "+pageIndex);
    pages.success(function(loadedData) {
        pageData.push(loadedData);
        completions.addPageComponents(pageIndex + 1, pageData[pageData.length-1]); 
        pageIndex += 1;
        if (pageIndex < numberOfPages) {
            loadPageData(pages, completions);
        }
    });
}

app.factory('pages', ['$http', function($http) {
    console.log("pages factory called with pageIndex = "+pageIndex);
    var url = 'json/page'+ (pageIndex + 1) +'.json';
    return $http.get(url)
        .success(function(loadedData) {
            return loadedData;
        })
        .error(function(loadedData) {
            return loadedData;
        });
}]);


/*Controller for menu, data fetched from factory*/
app.controller('menuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'content', function($scope, $http, content) {

    content.success(function(data) {
        $scope.pages = data;
    });

}]);


/*Controller for individual pages. Makes XHR to json page for pages data.
  Has function for calculating column widths*/
app.controller('pageCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', 'content', 'completions', function($scope, $routeParams, $http, content, completions) {

    $scope.page = pageData[$routeParams.pageId-1];

    $scope.getStyle = function(singleCase, device) {
        if (singleCase == undefined)
            return '';

        return assignBootstrap(singleCase, device);
    }    

    $scope.pageId = $routeParams.pageId;
}]);
```

So hopefully you can see, the 'content' factory gets called by 'menuCtrl'. It first loads the content.json file (a list of the page titles) then it calls 'loadPageData', a recursive function that should call the 'pages' factory on every required page, as it loads.

The problem is, those console.logs show that the 'pages' factory is getting called just once and BEFORE even the loadPageData function. Each html page is then being passed the same (first) set of data.

I presume I'm not using the 'pages' factory correctly, but I don't know what the correct options are.

If anyone has any pointers, I'd be keen to hear them.

**EDIT**
Thanks for the comments. I think I've realised what I need to know is: How do I set up a chain of promises ($http calls) dynamically? The number of pages will vary, so I can't hard-code them.

Comment: You can use $q.all() to synchronize the load.

Comment: OK - I've started googling that term, but if you could provide a bit more detail, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: it allows to prepare a list of promises to load before any action. I use to load lists from several RESTs before the start of the screen: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: do you really need to reload this data each route change? Or just load it once and cache it? Also note that to properly implement chained promises you need to stop using `success` which is deprecated as per docs

Comment: I'm trying not to reload the data at every route change. I'm trying to load all the data at the start, store it in an array and pass the correct data as needed. (I might be misunderstanding your question - let me know, if so). But thanks for the pointers.

Comment: What I really need to know, though, is how to set up the '$http.get's so they are chained. I'll obviously keep searching and reading, but if you'd like to provide an example, that would be great.

Comment: All of the examples I'm seeing have the chain hard-coded. With my project, the number of pages in e-learning modules will vary; How do I set up a chain of promises dynamically, as opposed to hard-coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing. Not sure if this is 100% best practise, but it seems to be working well:

```
app.factory('content', ['$http', 'completions', function($http, completions) {
    var url = 'json/content.js';
    return $http.get(url)
        .success(function(data) {
            // loop through pages and add corresponding page objects to completions.js service
            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                completions.addPage(data[i].title);
                numberOfPages += 1;
            }
            // load page .js files
            var tempData = getData(0, completions);            
            for (var i = 1; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
                (function (i) {
                    tempData = tempData.then(function() {
                        return getData(i, completions);
                    });
                }(i));
            }

            return data;
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            return data;
        });
}]);

// loads individual page data, stores in pageData and sets up SCORM objectives from completable components (in completions service)
function getData(id, completions) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'json/page'+ (id + 1) +'.js',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(d) {
        // push data into pageData array, for use later when pages are routed to
        pageData.push(d);

        // register this page's completable components in SCORM
        completions.addPageComponents(id + 1, d);

    }).fail(function() {
        console.log('ERROR loading page index '+id);
    });
}
```

I couldn't make sense of $q.all or promises, but a colleague pointed me to another SO answer that used something similar to the above.

When the 'content' factory is called, it calls the getData function to load the first .js file. Looping through up to the number of pages, I'm guessing the line...

```
tempData = tempData.then(...
```

...means that it waits for that load to complete before starting the next. The key thing for storing the currently loaded data is what happens in the getData.done function; The loaded data is pushed into pageData array for use later and the data is also passed into the completions service (to set up our objectives in SCORM).

All working as intended!